# Access TeamCity Environment variables with python script

Tags: python, environment-variables, teamcity

I am using TeamCity to test my code. I am using command line from TC and I am running a python test suite that tests the code.

I defined an environment variable (named "Server") and gave it a value ("production") and I want to pass it in a way that my python script will be able to access it and save it's value in the code.

I tried looking in TC documentation as well in Python's documentation and I couldn't find it.

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you should use [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ)

```
assert os.environ['Server'] == 'production'
```

Comment: I ran into an instance where this didn't work. The TC invocation on the build server would not see the environment variables. I believe it was because TeamCity was executing the script with "sudo". In that case, I just ended up making the environment variables that I needed parameters to the python script invocation. I wanted to leave that as a comment here in case anyone runs into the same issue in the future.